# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '=root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql

On my `Ubuntu` VM, I am trying to add several files into my sql database using the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd ~/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/data/retail-data/by-day/
for file in *.csv
do
        echo "inserting file '$file'"
sudo mysql -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"$f"' INTO TABLE sales_hour FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS" -u=root retail_data

done
```

but I am getting error

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '=root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps it sounds obvious but "*Access denied for user '`=root`' [&hellip;] using password: NO*" means is exactly what it says: you are not allowed to log into MySQL with a passwordless user called `=root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-u` parameter doesn't take an `=`: use `-u root` or `-uroot`

Comment: Thanks. There was one more issue. the variable name in the query should be `file`, not `f`